# Types of property 'estadoProducto' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Dispositivo'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Por que no puedo asignar los enum  "Dispositivo y Prioridad " de la siguiente forma en el type "TVVenta" ?

La sintaxis del enum es correcto creo, ya que se pueden asignar strings o numeros,
Alguna idea de en que lo estoy haciendo mal?

El error que me aparece es:

Types of property 'estadoProducto' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Dispositivo'.

```
enum Dispositivo {
    Apagado = 'Apagado',
    Prendido = 'Prendido'
}

enum Prioridad {
   A = 'A',
   M = 'M',
   B = 'B'
}

const tvPayload = {
    region: "Norte",
    pais: "Mexico",
    estadoProducto: "Apagado",
    canalVenta: "Online",
    prioridad: "string",
    fechaDeOrden: "01/29/2021",
    fechaDeEnvio: "01/30/2021",
    unidades: 4,
};


type TVjson = {
    region: string;
    pais: string;
    estadoProducto: string;
    canalVenta: string;
    prioridad: string;
    fechaDeOrden: string;
    fechaDeEnvio: string;
    unidades: number;
};


type TVVenta = {
    region: string;
    pais: string;
    estadoProducto: Dispositivo;
    canalVenta: string;
    prioridad: Prioridad;
    fechaDeOrden: Date;
    fechaDeEnvio: Date;
    unidades: number;
};

const handleJson = (json: TVjson): TVVenta => {
    return {
        ...json,
        fechaDeOrden: new Date(json.fechaDeOrden),
        fechaDeEnvio: new Date(json.fechaDeEnvio)
    }
}
```

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?,

estoy usando la version "typescript": "^3.9.4"

Comment: Dentro de un enum no se puede hacer eso, te aparece el siguiente error "Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members." @Marcos

Comment: HandleJson es una funcion que recibe TVjson y tiene que regresar un objeto de tipo TVVenta. @Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución es usar [`keyof typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-compile-time) para declarar las propiedades de `TVjson` que responden a un `enum` y en la función `handleJson` podemos usar dichos valores como claves de los `enum`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
type TVjson = {
    region: string;
    pais: string;
    estadoProducto: keyof typeof Dispositivo;
    canalVenta: string;
    prioridad:  keyof typeof Prioridad;
    fechaDeOrden: string;
    fechaDeEnvio: string;
    unidades: number;
};

/* resto del código */

const handleJson = (json: TVjson): TVVenta => {
    return {
        ...json,
        estadoProducto: Dispositivo[json.estadoProducto],
        prioridad: Prioridad[json.prioridad],
        fechaDeOrden: new Date(json.fechaDeOrden),
        fechaDeEnvio: new Date(json.fechaDeEnvio)
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIglgZwA4HsFwC5wG4qgbwCgoSoBBJAQwHNKATPAXigHIKb6UWAaY0gBQBOoOnAZRmLISLFdCAX0KFQkKELgpBY+gT7kJrMjz0BZAyxPHSAIXPWWCpQGMUIBBigZs-SgE8ANig6zESkUMLUGiAAXFAARABymhjAcbxhVIixcSbAAB5wLml6UMDunEIodGBOGCjZ7LQMxWFOlCCU-gBqoBiU2QDyIP5wIKnppEhamtp0DS2kAGbATgAWlDDAA4J0oNkADACMAPQATACcZ-unhwsky2sbwACiINgaBycAzPtXN3dQMAgWZlWIAFl48gA3EpCBhfEhgFAACpdABWCFcBlCpAiUVi7i0IGoMIylCyUEJoxJJTKfQYlWqtXqUAA1sBfChFp4EcAubBEKh0FhcKTSG0Ot1ev1KRgiTSMtMtHR6LE2Rz+fDEfz1DMVXQxfcVutNttdjFZfLDVAHiaXm8PpbqdagSCELFwBAAEbAQQw6GwrVI1E9EB9bElPGuAly50lTLup3E610iqCKo1OqxeDINCYHAoa0Szqhvoxq3xpWzWK65X0a22p5mvawSgpBvGp6vd4smBt4Au4H60FQT0+v0KGGEFxuDzrEB0fzAABSmJABgAFBjoyj0WuAJSxEPSiQAPl0YWEGDAgnXOLCJAAdM-tyAJg-SuUGemmVmBbnhQLABtV9H1Tb8M2ZABdd8HymDQ6zmNQq31EC10feC9XoGCSjCRtTR2FsxgAd1bFIt3Q-CtkIkB91gvDO02btHRIsjgAo1xHyo5iUH3EpFEUadXExJdH0CagN3nRcVzXDcvB8AIgjoKBKAQXdX33fcgA)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, el keyof typeof tambein se podria eliminar y dejar solamente los enum, lo probe y funciona